# Cambiar el Tamaño de un formulario

Tags: html, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un formulario **HTML** y **Bootstrap**, la cual quedo de esta manera:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-info text-center">
  <h5 style="color:white">Formulario de Pais</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body  border border-info p-5">
      <form class="text-center">
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center py-4">
    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Pais</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Crear Pais" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quisiera que me ayudaran en la manipulación de tamaño, me gustaría saber como cambiar el tamaño de mi formulario para que no se vea tan largo, como lo tiene actualmente. No lo he manipulado en **CSS** porque lo estoy haciendo en `Angular` y borre el archivo **CSS** que este genera. Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En las clases le eliminé `py-4` `p-5` y `my-4`. También eliminé un div vacío que estaba antes del botón.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-info text-center">
      <h5 style="color:white">Formulario de Pais</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body  border border-info">
      <form class="text-center">
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
          <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Pais</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Crear Pais" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block waves-effect z-depth-0" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```